# My Google Play store says refunded for a refund request I put in five days ago and I've still not gotten my money

Tags: google

I requested for a refund on a rubbish games five days ago. My history say refunded but I still haven't received the money, is this normal?

Comment: This is more a question of Google Play's payment practices,; really only tangentially Android-related.